# ARRAY Formula to sum two cells in the same row

Tags: google-sheets

I have the columns below (column I, J and K):

**Qty1, Qty2, TotalQty**

Where **TotalQty** for each row is simply the sum of the cells in columns I and J (Qty1 and Qty2).

How can I write an array formula that simply sums column I and J for each row?

I have the below but this just repeats the sum for the row the arrayformula is applied in to all cells below it:

```
ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A="","",SUM($I2:$J2)))
```

What I want it to do is calculate each row's I,J sum separately.

Answer (score 0):

try in K2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(I2:I10+J2:J10)
```

with if it would be:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A="";;I2:I+J2:J))
```

you can shorten it:

```
=INDEX(IF(A2:A="";;I2:I+J2:J))
```

or use a different approach like:

```
=QUERY(I2:J; "select I+J label I+J''")
```

or some more advanced techniques like:

```
=BYROW(I2:J; LAMBDA(x; SUM(x)))
```

or the old way:

```
=INDEX(MMULT(I2:J*1; SEQUENCE(2; 1; 1; ))
```

Comment: Thanks for the multiple solutions. I will stick with the second one as it is one I most comfortable with.

Answer (score 0):

BYROW or MAP will do the trick. For this case, you can try MAP:

```
=MAP(A2:A,I2:I,J2:J,LAMBDA(ax,ix,jx,IF(ax="","",ix+jx)))
```